# positioning two absolute elements horizontally without javascript

Tags: html, css, absolute

I have a page with a title bar and two columns underneath it. The two columns are positioned absolutely so they can extend their background colors to the bottom of the page. Here are the constraints:

- I want the right column's left edge to start where the left column's right edge ends.
- The text in the left column changes with some ajax requests. It needs to expand, so I can not use a fixed width on the left column.
- The right column's width doesn't matter. Its height must **at least** fill page vertically 100% to the bottom. If the content goes below the bottom of the page, the background should extend with it.

The idea is that the user will visit this front page and it will look "full", as in all three columns take up almost the entire page horizontally, and **must** take up the entire page vertically. As they scroll down the left column can end, and the right column can go on.

I have accomplished this using javascript.

```
$("#right").css('left', $("#left").width()+'px');
```

I do not want to use javascript. Can I remake this page with these constraints using CSS3 only?

http://jsfiddle.net/m3ta/BJFME/2/

Comment: Try this on the first element:

`float: left;`

Comment: I could not figure out how to use `float` to help me with this situation, could you please elaborate?

Comment: try float:left on the first div or the left div

Answer (score 0):

Based on the "float" hint this is the way to go:

1. re-arrange the left col to be inside the right col element
2. set the right col element to 100% width
3. set the left col to "float:left" and give it a height of 100%
4. check if you still need the "mid" elm ;)

CSS

```
#left {
    float:left;
    background: SkyBlue;
    height:100%;
}

#right {
    position: absolute;
    background: YellowGreen;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id = "mid">
    <div id = "right">

        <div id = "left">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum Something</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum Something 23</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum Something 23 and much more text</p>
        </div>

        <p>And here goes the content for the right part</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

see this forked fiddle for an example http://jsfiddle.net/UXGjt/

Comment: This looked really promising, but when a lot of content is added to the `right` element, the content spills over to the left of the page. Also, I should have specified that the background of the `right` element should continue down and to the right of the page if the content becomes very wide/long. http://jsfiddle.net/Pq6sP/

Answer (score 0):

Adding to foobored's post - since he was faster than I - Add Max-width to the left div. And as you expand - it goes no wider than 50% of the page while keeping text within itself.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lloanalas/UXGjt/2/)

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#top { height: 100px; background: orange }
#mid { position: absolute; top: 100px; bottom: 0; width: 100% }

#left {
    float:left;
    max-width: 50%;
    background: SkyBlue;
    height:100%;
}

#right {
    position: absolute;
    background: YellowGreen;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the content starts spilling out when many items are added to the right `div`. http://jsfiddle.net/B9Mr5/

Comment: Mind putting it on JSFiddle so I can see? ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#top { height: 100px; background: orange }
#mid { position: absolute; top: 100px; bottom: 0; width: 100% }

#left {
    float:left;
    max-width: 50%;
    background: SkyBlue;
    height:100%;
    width: auto;
}

#right {
    position: absolute;
    background: YellowGreen;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/UXGjt/4/).

Comment: The content spills out of the right `div` when the right column becomes too long. http://jsfiddle.net/B9Mr5/1/

Comment: @Joey in that you have your left div inside your right div, that is what creating the problem.

Comment: I think I'm getting closer, but this still seems to be a bit off: http://jsfiddle.net/B9Mr5/2/

Answer (score 0):

> If I have understood you correctly this is your solution:
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/BJFME/3/

```
#flexbox {      
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -webkit-box-align: start;

    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-pack: start;
    -moz-box-align: start;

    display: box;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    box-pack: start;
    box-align: start;

    overflow: hidden;
}
#flexbox .col {
    width: 27.333%;
    padding: 30px 3% 0;

    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
#flexbox .col p {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#flexbox .col:nth-child(1) {
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    box-ordinal-group: 2;
    background: #ccc;
}
#flexbox .col:nth-child(2) {
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    box-ordinal-group: 1;
    background: #eee;
}
#flexbox .col:nth-child(3) {
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    box-ordinal-group: 3;
    background: #eee;
}
```

> Just took the codes from this site:
>
> http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/
>
> There are more than one solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to acheive a table layout, try this http://jsfiddle.net/MtBXf/

```
<div id = "top"></div>
<div id = "mid">
    <div id = "left">
            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation </p>
        </div>
    <div id = "right">
        <p>And here goes the content for the right part</p>
    </div>
</div>



* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#top { height: 100px; background: orange }
#mid { display:table-row; top: 100px; bottom: 0; width: 100% }

#left, #right {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}
#left {
    background: SkyBlue;
}
#right {
    background: YellowGreen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following css 2.1 solution that works even in older IE versions:

```
<div id = "top"></div>
<div id = "mid">
    <div id = "left">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Somささsething</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Something 23dsdsdsdsd</p>
         <div id = "right">
            dsdsdsdsd
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#top { height: 100px; background: orange }
#mid { position: absolute; top: 100px; bottom: 0; width: 100% }

#left {
    position: absolute;
    background: SkyBlue;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#right {
    position: absolute;
    background: YellowGreen;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```